# django not checking elif condition views.py

Tags: python, django, if-statement

In my views.py if i provide only 1 elif condition its working but when i give 2 elif condition its not working

**In views.py**

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
        b=emp.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))

    elif request.user.admin.position == 'admin':
        a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
        b=emp.objects.filter(branch=request.user.admin.branch_name).aggregate(Count('id'))

    
    elif request.user.emp.position == 'employee':   
        a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
        b=emp.objects.filter(branch=request.user.emp.branch).aggregate(Count('id'))
```

Comment: ***when i give 2 elif condition its not working*** - what is not working? try to debug your code.

Comment: its not checking the second elif condition,it gives error user has no admin when i login with emp

Comment: Provide your models

Comment: in my project i have 3 user category that user have different permissions to view dashboard superuser,admin working correctly but when i login emp it shows error when i remove admin emp is working

Comment: share your models by updating your question.

Answer (score 1):

A `OneToOneField` actually is a `ForeignKey` field with a `unique=True` constraint
and a `OneToOneField` field does not mean that the referenced model always has a `admin` and `emp` object(in your case). This is why in some case if `user.admin` or `user.emp` for some user not exists then it raises an `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`.

So you have to either use `try-except` and raise `exception` if object does not exists.

In views.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def dashboard(request):
    try:
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
            b=emp.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
        elif request.user.admin.position == 'admin':
            a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
            b=emp.objects.filter(branch=request.user.admin.branch_name).aggregate(Count('id'))
       elif request.user.emp.position == 'employee':   
            a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
            b=emp.objects.filter(branch=request.user.emp.branch).aggregate(Count('id'))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # hanlde your case when both model object does not exist.
    else:
        # this block is excuted only if try except don't raise exception
```

Or you can also user Python's `hasattr()` method.

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
        b=emp.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
    elif hasattr(request.user, 'admin') and request.user.admin.position == 'admin':
        a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
        b=emp.objects.filter(branch=request.user.admin.branch_name).aggregate(Count('id'))
    elif hasattr(request.user, 'position') and request.user.emp.position == 'employee':   
        a=branch.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
        b=emp.objects.filter(branch=request.user.emp.branch).aggregate(Count('id'))
```

You can see more details about `OneToOneField` in official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) where you will get to know about both `ObjectDoesNotExist` and `hasattr`

Comment: in my project i have 3 user category that user have different permissions to view dashboard  superuser,admin working correctly but when i login emp it shows error when i remove admin emp is working

Comment: when you login with emp what error it is showing ?

Comment: Its showing RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /
User has no admin

Comment: have you changed accordingly to my answer as elif request.user.emp.position == 'admin'. RelatedObjectDoesNotExist means your user object has no admin as column

Comment: but when i login  with admin `elif request.user.admin.position == 'admin':` this condition need and when i login with emp  `elif request.user.emp.position == 'employee': ` this condition needed....this is problem i facing

Comment: do you have emp and admin as columns in your user model ?

Comment: ```class emp(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,null=False)
    lastname=models.CharField(default='',max_length=5,null=False) 
                 position=models.CharField(default='')                        class admin(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,null=False)
    lastname=models.CharField(default='',max_length=5,null=False) 
    position=models.CharField(default='',)```

Comment: @nivash see I have updated my answer.